# How can we conditionally route to a different URL in Spring Cloud Gateway? Is there a reference sample?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

Trying to change the exchange target URL conditionally. Is there a way this can be achieved in Spring Cloud Gateway?

To elaborate, upon inspecting a particular cookie value in the incoming request, I would like to route it to a different URL.

Answer (score 2):

We do something similar with request headers [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/blob/1f6f762b15c8049b77993d8b1cdb0fdf3b87bd47/spring-cloud-gateway-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/gateway/filter/factory/RequestHeaderToRequestUriGatewayFilterFactory.java). We have an [abstract filter](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/blob/1f6f762b15c8049b77993d8b1cdb0fdf3b87bd47/spring-cloud-gateway-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/gateway/filter/factory/AbstractChangeRequestUriGatewayFilterFactory.java) that handles setting the uri correctly, you just have to determine the uri from the `ServerWebExchange`.

```
public class CookieToRequestUriGatewayFilterFactory extends
        AbstractChangeRequestUriGatewayFilterFactory<AbstractGatewayFilterFactory.NameConfig> {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(RequestHeaderToRequestUriGatewayFilterFactory.class);

    public RequestHeaderToRequestUriGatewayFilterFactory() {
        super(NameConfig.class);
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> shortcutFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList(NAME_KEY);
    }

    @Override
    protected Optional<URI> determineRequestUri(ServerWebExchange exchange,
            NameConfig config) {
        String cookieValue = exchange.getRequest().getCookies().getFirst(config.getName());
        String requestUrl = determineUrlFromCookie(cookieValue);
        return Optional.ofNullable(requestUrl).map(url -> {
            try {
                return new URL(url).toURI();
            }
            catch (MalformedURLException | URISyntaxException e) {
                log.info("Request url is invalid : url={}, error={}", requestUrl,
                        e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

It would be up to you to implement `determineUrlFromCookie()`.